# org-mode How to use latex nested environments?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, preview-latex

I want to use a `matrix` environment that is included in an outer environment, so:

```
Environment:
\begin{equation*}
\left|
\begin{matrix}
a_1 & b_1\\
a_2 & b_2
\end{matrix}
\right|
\end{equation*}

Display--math:
\[
\left|
\begin{matrix}
a_1 & b_1\\
a_2 & b_2
\end{matrix}
\right|
\]

Inline--math:
\(
\left|
\begin{matrix}
a_1 & b_1\\
a_2 & b_2
\end{matrix}
\right|
\)
```

But for the second and third cases (display-math and inline-math) the preview and export to latex are failed:

exported LaTeX:

```
Environment:
\begin{equation*}
\left|
\begin{matrix}
a_1 & b_1\\
a_2 & b_2
\end{matrix}
\right|
\end{equation*}

Display--math:
$\backslash$[
\left|
\begin{matrix}
a_1 & b_1\\
a_2 & b_2
\end{matrix}
\right|
$\backslash$]

Inline--math:
$\backslash$(
\left|
\begin{matrix}
a_1 & b_1\\
a_2 & b_2
\end{matrix}
\right|
$\backslash$)
\end{document}
```

org-mode preview:

[image]

Emacs 26.3

Org-mode 9.3.8

Comment: I can reproduce it with 9.4 and I believe it is a bug. Please consider submitting a bug report with `M-x org-submit-bug-report RET`.

Comment: I can reproduce it with Org 9.3 and Emacs 27.1. Having [this](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Yc3nY7ZntW/) in an Org buffer produces [this LaTeX file](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/84J95K2w4b/) by pressing `C-c C-e l L`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this is [not a bug](https://orgmode.org/list/87v9g8awp5.fsf@nicolasgoaziou.fr/):

nested `\begin{...}` should not start the line and therefore is not seen as starting a new LaTeX block:

```
Inline-math:
\(
\left|\begin{matrix}
a_1 & b_1\\
a_2 & b_2
\end{matrix}\right|
\)
```

Comment: Thanks for checking!